# AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring and Registration of Classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

i am converting my xml based spring app to java config and the hell break lose. I have several @config classes and my problem is the registration of MyWebConfiguration.class. This class is a child of RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration and has of course some @bean methods in it. But no @bean method is invoked, even though the registration went w/o problems.

Are there any issues when overriding both getRootConfigClasses() and getServletConfigClasses() ?

If i put the MyWebConfiguration class into getRootConfigClasses(), it will at least run those @bean methods.

```
public class AppInitializer extends
       AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

...
@Override
protected final Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{CoreConfiguration.class, JpaConfiguration.class,
            ShiroSecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected final Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{MyWebConfiguration.class};
}
}
```

Furthermore i have severe Problems using @Resource in@Configuration classes to obtain a bean from a different configuration class. But this is just a side issue i have at the moment.

The issue with @Bean methods which wont get fired is the most serious one. Thanks for any infos.

Comment: Did you add `@Configuration` annotation to your class where your `@Bean`'s take place ?

Comment: Yes of course i have.

Comment: One more check: did you put `@ComponentScan` (usually on your main class) ?

Comment: ComponentScan is not responsible for my @Configuration classes. I supplied them via AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Comment: i will give that up. Perhaps it has something to do with circular references because i get some warnings about that. XML based configuration handles this A LOT better. Java Config is dead for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I had complex web.xml and I successfully moved to java configuration. You can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495411/4090550) for the same.